# ValueError when checking if variable is None or numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, is-empty

I'd like to check if variable is None or numpy.array. I've implemented `check_a` function to do this.

```
def check_a(a):
    if not a:
        print "please initialize a"

a = None
check_a(a)
a = np.array([1,2])
check_a(a)
```

But, this code raises ValueError. What is the straight forward way?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-0201c81c185e> in <module>()
      6 check_a(a)
      7 a = np.array([1,2])
----> 8 check_a(a)

<ipython-input-41-0201c81c185e> in check_a(a)
      1 def check_a(a):
----> 2     if not a:
      3         print "please initialize a"
      4 
      5 a = None

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: This `ValueError` is one of the most common `numpy` questions.  It means `not a` produces a boolean array, with (in this case) 2 values.  This boolean array cannot be used as an `if` condition!  The `is None` alternative is good to know, but you should also understand this error.

Comment: @hpaulj: Not quite - you can't overload `not`, so the error actually happens when `not` tries to treat the array as a single boolean and finds out it can't. If it had been `~a`, that would have used NumPy's overload and failed when `if` tries to use the negated array as a single boolean.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Using `not a` to test whether `a` is `None` assumes that the other possible values of `a` have a truth value of `True`. However, most NumPy arrays don't have a truth value at all, and `not` cannot be applied to them.

If you want to test whether an object is `None`, the most general, reliable way is to literally use an `is` check against `None`:

```
if a is None:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

This doesn't depend on objects having a truth value, so it works with NumPy arrays.

Note that the test has to be `is`, not `==`. `is` is an object identity test. `==` is whatever the arguments say it is, and NumPy arrays say it's a broadcasted elementwise equality comparison, producing a boolean array:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(5)
>>> a == None
array([False, False, False, False, False])
>>> if a == None:
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
 Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

On the other side of things, if you want to test whether an object is a NumPy array, you can test its type:

```
# Careful - the type is np.ndarray, not np.array. np.array is a factory function.
if type(a) is np.ndarray:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

You can also use `isinstance`, which will also return `True` for subclasses of that type (if that is what you want). Considering how terrible and incompatible `np.matrix` is, you may not actually want this:

```
# Again, ndarray, not array, because array is a factory function.
if isinstance(a, np.ndarray):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: which do you recommend is the "best" solution?

Comment: Thanks! The `isinstance(a, np.ndarray)` way looks cleanest to me. The company I recently joined does the `is not None` check and it makes my pythonic alarms blare every time I read it.

Answer (score -1):

To stick to `==` without consideration of the other type, the following is also possible.
`type(a) == type(None)`