# Check if variable is None or numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy

I look up in a table if keys have associated arrays, or not. By design, my `table.__getitem__()` somtimes returns `None` rather than `KeyError`-s.  I would like this value to be either `None`, or the numpy array associated with `w`.

```
value = table[w] or table[w.lower()]
# value should be a numpy array, or None
if value is not None:
    stack = np.vstack((stack, value))
```

Only if I go with the above code, and the first lookup is a match, I get :

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

and if I go with `value = table[w].any() or table[w.lower()].any()`, then if it's a mismatch, I expectedly bump into :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'any'
```

I must be missing the correct way to do this, how to do ?

Comment: Obvious repost of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783921), because the correct answer there doesn't satisfy my need. I'd want a shorter way than `if table[w] is not None: ... elif table[w.lower()] is not None: ... else`, if possible.

Comment: @Goyo: `v = a or b` raises the `ValueError` if `a` is an array (not if `a` is `None` and `b` is an array though)

Comment: a = None .... isinstance(a, (type(None)))  # True .... if a is anything else, it will return false.  Obviously only useful to branch between None and if you can guarantee that 'a' will be some incarnation of an array

Comment: @Nikana Your question is not clear. " I would like this value to be either `None`..." when do you want it to be None? "or the numpy array associated with `w`" What's the associated array? `table[w]`? `table[w.lower()]`? The errors you are getting are to be expected but I do not understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Goyo: I want value to be None if table returns none on w, and none on w.lower(). Else, to be the first non-None value (so yes, ideally, table[w]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC this should work:

```
value = table[w]
if value is None:
    value = table[w.lower()]
```

Answer (score 14):

```
if type(value) is numpy.ndarray:
    #do numpy things
else
    # Handle None
```

Though the above would work, I would suggest to keep signatures simple and consistent, ie table[w] should always return numpy array. In case of None, return empty array.

Comment: so do I have one such block with w and another with w.lower() ? that's quite verbose, isn't it ?

Answer (score 8):

The question is answered, but other folks who encounter this error may want a general solution.  With the idea of being explicit in mind we can use the function [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).  Here is a working example.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = None
for itm in [a,b]:
    isinstance(itm,np.ndarray)
```

So in the context of the question

```
value = table[w]
if not isinstance(value,np.ndarray):
    value = table[w.lower()]
```

Comment: Sorry but this has very little to do with the question. The question is about the `value = ???` part.

Comment: This is the same answer as your accepted answer just more explicit.  The problem is that you cannot check to see if an array == None (the error you observed).  But you can use the is instance that I showed above.  I edited the above comment.

Comment: I can very much check if `value == None`, that's what the accepted answer does. What I would have loved is a one liner that assigns the first non-None value out of `[table[w], table[w.lower()]]` if any, or else None. The accepted answer does that perfectly, in 3 lines. I don't understand your contribution.

Comment: using `is` works in this case, but using == throws the ValueError you saw above.  Good Python code is explicit.  I am showing you how to test if value is an array not if it is None... which is better Python code.  I refer you to the Zen of Python if this is still hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

```
value = table.get(w, table.get(w.lower()))
```

So if `table[w]` is not there you will get `table[w.lower()]` and if that's not there you'll get `None`.

Comment: Ooh, interesting. Though... what happens if the default value is None, does it fail, or accept that ? And why would it default to the default if the first does return something, i.e. None ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Every function in Python implicitly returns `None` if nothing else is specified: the default value is what is assigned if the first returns `None`

Comment: Note that OP mentioned that their `__getitem__` implementation won't always raise a `KeyError`. Also `table.get(w.lower())` won't be lazily evaluated.

Comment: OP says it **sometimes** returns `None` instead of `KeyError` so I assumed `table` is just a normal `dict` filled with numpy arrays and `None`s. But good point on the laziness.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `type` operator!

```
if type(a) == type(None):
    # it's None
else:
    # it's something else, possible a numpy matrix
```