# Transfer NaN values from one numpy array to another

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I work with geographic data and have large raster files I import into python with `gdal`. To process them, I convert them to `numpy` arrays.

I create an empty array that gets filled with data in a loop. However, I need the NaN values to be at the same location as in my imported rater file.

```
data = ds.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
data = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
data[data==-9999] = np.nan # set all -9999 as no data value

cols, rows = data.shape
dataOut = np.zeros([ds.RasterYSize, ds.RasterXSize]) # create empty array with zeros
for c in range(cols):
    for r in range(rows):
        dataOut[c][r] = np.nan if isinstance(data[c][r], np.ndarray) else dataOut[c][r]
```

So I want my NaN values from my data array to be transferred to my dataOut array. None of those solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783987/4124803) wored for me...the dataOut array still holds only zeros.

Comment: Why are you checking `if isinstance(data[c][r], no.ndarray)`? That is never going to be true for a 2 dimensional array... You probably just want `dataOut[np.isnan(data))`

Comment: That's not working unfortunately (without error message, just no change at all). dataOut still holds only 0's instead of the NaN's in those positions as in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself...[np.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) is the solution:

```
for c in range(cols):
    for r in range(rows):
        dataOut[c][r] = np.nan if np.isnan(data[c][r]) else dataOut[c][r]
```

Comment: You shouldn't loop. you want `dataOut[np.isnan(data)] = np.nan` which was what I was trying to write above.