# How to check if an object is an np.array()?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to build a code that checks whether a given object is an np.array() in python.

`if isinstance(obj,np.array())` doesn't seem to work.

I would truly appreciate any help.

Comment: np.ndarray, not np.array(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783987/483620

Comment: Want to be mindful of subclasses too.

Answer (score 21):

`isinstance(obj, numpy.ndarray)` may work

Answer (score 5):

**You could compare the type of the object being passed to the checking function with 'np.ndarray' to check if the given object is indeed an np.ndarray**

The sample code snippet for the same should look something like this :

```
if isinstance(obj,np.ndarray):
    # proceed -> is an np array
else
    # Not an np.ndarray
```

Comment: `isinstance` is the proper check in almost every case.  This code will fail if `value` is an instance of a subclass of `numpy.ndarray`.

Answer (score 2):

Below code seems to work. Use `numpy.ndarray`.

```
import numpy as np

l = [1,2,3,4]

l_arr = np.array(l)

if isinstance(l_arr, np.ndarray):
    print("Type is np.array")
else:
    print("Type is not np.array")
```

Output:

```
Type is np.array
```

Answer (score 0):

The `type` of what `numpy.array` returns is `numpy.ndarray`.  You can determine that in the `repl` by calling `type(numpy.array([]))`.  Note that this trick works even for things where the raw class is not publicly accessible.  It's generally better to use the direct reference, but storing the return from `type(someobj)` for later comparison does have its place.